# Can you load all assets inside an Addressable folder?

Tags: unity, assets, assetbundle

So, I have a folder marked as addressable. This folder has many sub-folders, which might have more sub-folders, ultimately having some `.png` images.

I would like to load every single `Sprite` found in my main folder and its children (i.e. recursively).

```
public static AsyncOperationHandle<IList<TObject>> LoadAssets<TObject>(IList<IResourceLocation> locations, Action<TObject> callback);
public static AsyncOperationHandle<IList<TObject>> LoadAssetsAsync<TObject>(object key, Action<TObject> callback);
public static AsyncOperationHandle<IList<TObject>> LoadAssetsAsync<TObject>(IList<object> keys, Action<TObject> callback, MergeMode mode);
public static AsyncOperationHandle<IList<TObject>> LoadAssetsAsync<TObject>(IList<IResourceLocation> locations, Action<TObject> callback);
```

The first, third and fourth seem to take a list of keys for individual addressable assets (e.g. the actual Sprites), which is not what I want. I just want to provide the key for the parent folder, and then get all the sprites in it or its sub-folders.

So, the second function seems a bit promising. I would've expected to use it like this:

```
Addressables.LoadAssetsAsync<List<Sprite>>("Assets/MyMainFolder", myCallback);
```

But it just tells me that the key is invalid. I've made sure that the folder is addressable, it has that key, and the group has been built.

So my question is: is there a way to load every addressable asset inside an addressable folder? Like how AssetBundles worked.

Unity 2019.3.0f3.

Comment: [This is the first search result I get for "unity addressable folder", suggesting using a label on the parent directory to label all the sprites, and then LoadAssets by label](https://forum.unity.com/threads/loading-addressable-directory.657049/). Have you tried something like this?

Comment: You could do a workaround if you had an addressable folder build as a Remote Catalog. Then you could get its `IResourceLocator` and enumerate all its keys.